# Xcode 8 Auto Layout Constraints not working as expected. Very basic setup with centering plus an issue with pins. Video attached

Tags: xcode, autolayout, constraints

I am having trouble getting a grasp on how auto-layout constraints work. In theory, one should be able to add a label to the storyboard, then assign a horizontal centre constraint and it should be centred on all devices, correct? However, when I do that, it does NOT stay centred UNLESS I also add a vertical spacing constraint. However, if I test the app it IS centred (without the vertical spacing constraint). This is causing me great confusion.

Secondly, if I add a text input, expand it to full width, then add pin the left and right side, it does NOT maintain the pins in other views. And instead there is this dotted box inside a solid orange line box which is centred, but the element itself is not.

I am at a loss please help. I have attached a video of me doing it in Xcode. Both issues are in there First the centring issue, next to the pinning issue. Thank you!

VIDEO OF THE ISSUES HERE:
https://vid.me/XxFo

Comment: Show your screenshots what you tried instead of writing theory.

Comment: @vaibhav That link is a complete video of both issues, thought that would be a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0):

-- Red lines mean Constraints are ambiguous. Yellow means warning, Its show you the runtime demonstration of view.

- View need four constraint to satisfy its full position.

  x, y, width and height

When you give only center horizontally constraint, this is not enough you have to specify the y position as well. Label get its width and height from its text length and text font size.

Though constraints are ambiguous and in preview you are not getting correct result but once you give center constraint, it will be center at runtime.

Run the app and it should be in center horizontally.